# Как передать данные от дочернего элемента в родительский React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

я делаю проект, в котором мне нужно по нажатию на маркер передать данные в родительский элемент

Родительский компонент должен принять данные(в моем случае это id)

```
export default function App() {

    return(<>
    <Menu id=()> //Сюда должно попасть значение id из дочернего элемента 
    <Map
        initialViewState={{
          latitude: 56,
          longitude: 38,
          zoom: 10,
          bearing: 0,
          pitch: 0,
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/yxunker/clcjn4cy1001w15oe7co855oq" 
        mapboxAccessToken={TOKEN}
      >    
        <PopupBox lat={53.83} lon={53.83} title={"Test"} />
    </Map>
    </>
    );
}
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
export default function PopupBox (props: PopupProps ) {

    return ( 
          <Marker latitude={props.lat} longitude={props.lon} anchor="bottom" 
          onClick = ()> //По нажатию должен передать id в родительский компонент
            <h1></h1>
            <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/cat-png/cat-png-17.png" width={100} height={100} alt="" />
            
          </Marker>
    )
  }
```

Comment: В родительском компоненте создайте стейт `useState` и передайте пропсами от него сеттер и если нужно, то и значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все оказалось настолько просто